# The group of bijections of an infinite set that move only finitely many elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

If someone can prove the following and give me an easy to understand explanation I would appreciate it! I have tried what omnomnomnom has suggsetd in the hints, but can't figure this out.

A(S) is defined to be the set of all bijections from S to S

A(S) has the following properties.
[image]

> Let $S$ be an infinite set and let $M\subset A(S)$ be the set of all elements $f\in A(S)$ such that $f(s)\neq s$ for at most a finite number of $s\in S$. Prove that:
>
> 1. $f,g\in M$ implies that $f\circ g\in M$.
> 2. $f\in M$ implies that $f^{-1}\in M$.

Questions. Is M an infinite set? can it be the same as A(S)? What happens in number 1 when g is f inverse? You would get the identity function which fails the condition.

Comment: The problem as stated makes no sense. Does the book specify what $A(S)$ is?

Comment: From a previous question from the same asker: *"A(S) is defined to be the set of all bijections from S to S"*

Comment: We should also specify that $fg$ refers to the composition $f \circ g$

Comment: @Stevenlynn what have you tried so far?  At the very least, (b) should be easier than (a), so maybe you should start by taking a stab at that, and telling us if/where you get stuck.

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this problem.

Comment: By the way, the identity function doesn't violate the condition you gave for $M$.  The functions in $M$ don't have to rearrange any elements, and, if they do, they only shuffle at most finitely many of them.  They leave the rest alone.

Comment: Doesn't the identity function make all elements map to themselves? Which violates the f(s) != s

Comment: @StevenLynn, there's a big difference between "$f(s)\neq s$" and "$f(s)\neq s$ for at most a finite number of points."  The former says that $f$ shuffles all points (i.e. $f$ is a derangement), and the latter says that $f(s)=s$ 'most of the time.'  Such an $f$ leaves most elements of $S$ fixed, and it shuffles around at most finitely many points.  The identity function certainly satisfies "$f(s)\neq s$ for at most finitely many points."

Comment: Yeah I understand that though!The "at most a finite number of points" throw me off, but I figured it out. Thanks! (:

Answer (score 2):

**Hint for 2:** Suppose that $f \in M$.  Let $S' \subset S$ denote the set of $s \in S$ such that $f(s) \neq s$.  We know that $S'$ is finite (and possibly empty).

Let $S''$ denote the set of $s \in S$ such that $f^{-1}(s) \neq s$.  We'd like to somehow conclude that $S''$ is finite.

One way to do so is to show that the restriction of $f$ to $S'$ gives a bijection from $S'$ to $S''$ (which would mean that the sets have the same cardinality).  How can we show that this is the case?

---

**Hint for 1:** Suppose that $f,g \in M$.  Let $S' \subset S$ denote the set of $s \in S$ such that $f(s) \neq s$.  Let $S'' \subset S$ denote the set of $s \in S$ such that $g(s) \neq s$.

Let $S'''$ denote the set of $s \in S$ such that $f(g(s)) \neq s$.  How does $S'''$ relate to $S'$ and $S''$?

Suppose that $f(g(s)) \neq s$. If $g(s) = s$, then $f(g(s))$ can't be $g(s) = s$.  Similarly, if $f(g(s)) = g(s)$, then $g(s) \neq s$.  What can we conclude?

---

To answer your questions:

> Is M an infinite set?

Yes, as it so happens.

> can it be the same as A(S)?

We can say that $M = A(S)$ if and only if $S$ is a finite set.  It is said that $S$ is infinite in the beginning of the question.

> What happens in number 1 when g is f inverse? You would get the identity function which fails the condition

The identity function does *not* fail the condition.  If $f$ is the identity function, then there are $0$ $s \in S$ such that $f(s) \neq s$.  So, there are indeed finitely many $s$ such that $f(s) \neq s$.

---

It may help to look at an example.  Suppose $S = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$.  Consider the function $$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x+1 & x \text{ is odd }\\
x-1 & x \text{ is even }
\end{cases}
$$
How do we know that $f \in A(S)$ but $f \notin M$?  Now, consider the function 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x + 1 & 1 \leq x \leq 99\\
1 & x = 100\\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Why is $f \in M$?

Comment: Does this hint give you an idea of where to start? Can you see how the steps that I've taken might end up being useful?  Is there any statement that I could clarify?  Let me know.

Comment: The more I look at this problem the more confused I get. I am not quite sure if I understand what the question is even asking.

Comment: Start by trying to understand what 2 is asking.  We can interpret "$\in M$" as meaning "is a function ($f$) satisfying the property $f(s) \neq s$ for at most finitely many elements $s$".  So, the question asks "if we know that $f$ satisfies this property, how do we show that $f^{-1}$ satisfies this property?"  Does that part, at the very least, make sense?

Comment: Alright that makes sense now.

Comment: Does the first question make sense as well?  Now that you understand the question, is my hint starting to make more sense?

Comment: First question is making sense too. Your hint is making much more sense now! Thanks a billion!

Comment: In you hint for number 1 you ask "How does S′′′ relate to S′ and S′′?" Are S′′and S′ subsets of S′′′? Is that how they relate?

Comment: For Number 2 can't I just show that f-1 maps back to every element of f?

Comment: @StevenLynn what is "an element of $f$"?  You need to show that $f|_{S'}:S' \to S''$ is both one to one and onto.

Comment: Yeah I am lost and not getting this. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: See my update.  Maybe that helps?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I think you mean $M=A(S)$ if and only if $S$ is finite.

Comment: @JoshKeneda whoops! Yes, that.

Comment: So f belongs to M because is contains all permutations of maps expect for the map where no elements don't match up with the same element.